# Working with office.js using promise pattern

Tags: javascript, promise, office-2013, office-app

Currently I've started developing some **Apps for Office 2013**. To develop these apps I'm using **office.js** which is designed to work with Excel worksheets for example.

Most of the APIs are like:

```
document.getSelectedDataAsync(p1, p2, function(asyncResult)
{
    if (asyncResult.status == 'success')
        // do something with asyncResult.value
    else if (asyncResult.status == 'fail')
        // show asyncResult.error as Error
});
```

I don't like this type of asynchronous programming. Rather I prefer to use **promises** and write something like:

```
document.getSelectedDataAsync(p1, p2)
    .done(function(result)
    {
        // do something with result
    })
    .fail(function(error)
    {
        // show error message 
    })
```

Is there any way to use office.js API using promises like above?

Answer (score 1):

Sure thing - this example is using [the bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) promise library. Basically, we're converting a callback API to promises:

```
function promisify(fn){ // take a function and return a promise version
     return function(){
          var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
          return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
               args.push(function(asyncResult){
                    if(asyncResult.status === 'success') resolve(asyncResult.value);
                    else reject(asyncResult.error);
               }); 
               fn.apply(this, args); // call function   
          }.bind(this)); // fixate `this`
     };
}
```

This would let you do something like:

```
document.getSelectedDataPromise = promisify(document.getSelectedDataAsync);
document.getSelectedDataPromise(p1, p2).then(function(result){
   // do something with result
}).catch(function(err){
   // handle error
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest form of working around this is by replacing the callback with a custom one which resolves a promise. Note that the below implementation uses the ES6 promises which are available in Chrome:

```
        function toPromise () {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            var self = this;
            return new Promise(function (reject, resolve) {
                var callback = function () {
                    if (arguments[0] instanceof Error) {
                        return reject.apply(null, arguments);
                    }

                    resolve.apply(arguments);
                };

                args.push(callback);
                self.apply(self, args);
            });
        }

        Function.prototype.toPromise = toPromise;

        document.getSelectedDataAsync.toPromise(p1, p2).then(function () {
            //success
        }).catch(function () {
            //error
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using ES 6. And I'm looking for an easier way, maybe a library which made this happen. Like new versions of jQuery which supports promise pattern for their ajax calls.

Comment: You can replace the promises with whatever you like. And if no such library exists then you should consider doing it yourself.

Comment: Resolution is always of a single thing.